# Creating a html link from a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to convert something like this:

`@Username`

into:

`<a href="Username">Username</a>`

Can't find a RegEx for it anywhere though. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Beware of input like `<img alt="@username">` -- you don't want to insert a <a> tag inside another tag's attribute value.  As a result, your best bet is actually to construct a proper dom tree.

Comment: _Can't find a RegEx for it anywhere_ Try first, you're not going to find all regex on the internet, it's worth learning. You can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) function for this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

I would also recommend you read the [documentation on regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "Sample text @Username sample text.";
$new_str = preg_replace( '\@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str );

echo $new_str;
?>
```

I think that's gonna work.